# how to use sendEnvelopeWithStatus method (android api 21)

Tags: android, telephonymanager, sim-card

I am novice on android development, actually i am developing an application who communicate with SIM card.

I looked to the API updates added recently on Android 5.1.1, and I found the method `sendEnvelopeWithStatus` which allows to send data to SIM card,

More exactly, I want a button, once clicked it execute this method.
somebody can help me to implement this method in my code?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Use the `TelephonyManager` class? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#sendEnvelopeWithStatus(java.lang.String) What is your exact problem?